# How to unflag a wrongly flagged Answer or Question?

Tags: discussion

I wrongly flagged an Answer as "Not an answer". I know it's wrongly flagged, and will be declined. I found it in [my flagged statistics](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/22728). But can't unflag the Answer again.

So, How to unflag a wrongly flagged Answer or Question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You [cannot undo a flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags). I wouldn’t worry too much about it. If your flags are wrong too often we will let you know that privately and soon enough.